# Google Places direction API Autocomplete set the initial location

Tags: javascript, google-maps, autocomplete

I m using draggable markers + 2 autocompletes to get directions.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-draggable.

I have a listener who catch events when marker has a new position.

```
  google.maps.event.addListener(directionsDisplay, 'directions_changed', function () {
                var place1 = autocompleteFrom.getPlace();
                var coord1 = [place1.geometry.location.lat(), place1.geometry.location.lng()];

               var place2 = autocompleteTo.getPlace();
                var coord2 = [place2.geometry.location.lat(), place1.geometry.location.lng()];
            });
```

The problem is autocompleteFrom.getPlace() returns undefined when user has not enter a place in the autocomplete search box.

Is it possible to setup a default location for the autocompletes ?

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry because I don't have enough reputation to comment.

You could set default location for `place1`, this is more simple than set default for autocompleteform.

Comment: Nice suggestion. i will try with that.